# How can I specify which shiny account to use when deploying?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I just want to ask about shiny accounts, I have two shiny registered accounts and now when I want to deploy I saw error like this

```
Do you want to proceed with deployment? [Y/n]: y
Error: Please specify the account which you want to deploy the application to (there is more than one account registered on this system).
```

So my question is how to specify the account that I want to used it in deploy application, when I just tried to run like this

```
    shinyapps::setAccountInfo(name='xxxx', 
                              token='13SDADASDSADAD9FCCEC48C016D5D97',
                              secret='863pLqbfaxeradasdafasfsadxzadadXgi2NfXh')
setwd('D:/ASD/test')
library(shinyapps)
deployApp()
```

I still got same error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to top menu your Rstudio-> Tools-> ShinnyApps -> Manage Accounts

Comment: in the latest version of RStudio you need to go to RStudio -> Preferences -> Publishing -> and then select the account you wish to deploy from.

Comment: RStudio > Tools > Global Options > Publishing.

Answer (score 6):

There are mainly two different parameters to set up: the `name` and the `account`, each used in a different function. Previous answers did not make this altogether clear, so let me add explanations.

**Step 1: Set `name` via `setAccountInfo()`:**

Go to https://www.shinyapps.io/admin/#/dashboard and get your personal name/token/secret, e.g. **"myName" / "myToken" / "mySecret"**. You'll need all three to authorize your account.

```
library(shiny)
library(rsconnect)
rsconnect::setAccountInfo(
    name = "myName", 
    token = "myToken",
    secret = "mySecret")
```

You're now ready to deploy your apps. If you have a single account, that is all you need to do. But with multiple accounts, you also need to set the `account` explicitly in the `deployApp()` function:

**Step 2: Set `account` via `deployApp():`**

```
setwd("my/local/dir/") # or set the full path below
rsconnect::deployApp("myAppNameOffline", 
    appName = "myAppNameOnline", 
    account = "myname")
```

**Bonus:** If you set option `appName` explicitly your app can have a different name online as it does offline, e.g. `"myapp-version-999"` can simply become `"myapp"` online.

Comment: This answer is also useful for deploying non-interactively (e.g. via cronjobs)

Answer (score 2):

If you have multiple accounts on shinyapps.io, specify the account name while deploying the app

1. get a list of accounts
2. deploy it to the desired account

   accounts(server = NULL)
   shinyapps::deployApp('./AppPath',account='second_account_name')

Comment: deployApp(account='newaccountname')

Answer (score 2):

Use the following command to remove all the accounts

```
removeAccount("user")
```

Then, add reconfigure your rsconnet using the follwoing functions

```
rsconnect::setAccountInfo(name, token, secret)
```

Answer (score 1):

In RStudio go to: `Tools => Global Options => Publishing`
and remove useless users.